# selenium python find_elements не проходит по всем элементам страницы

Tags: python, selenium

Пытаюсь найти список всех элементов на странице, но web_driver.find_elements выдает только один элемент, хотя их на странице около десятка, попадающих под шаблон link_model

```
srch_link_list = web_driver.find_elements(
                By.XPATH, f"//*[@class='summary']/p/a[contains(text(), '{link_model}')]")
            logger.debug(f'srch_link_list = {srch_link_list}')
```

Результат:

```
Search for all links to bugs that meet the conditions
08:16:43.138 | DEBUG    | __main__:search_link:402 - srch_link_list = [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="71e40208840934aa98d6f516135da83c", element="cf5b4ef3-f619-4428-b465-3424c8d437a6")>]
08:16:43.139 | DEBUG    | __main__:search_link:406 - *** search_link *** return [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="71e40208840934aa98d6f516135da83c", element="cf5b4ef3-f619-4428-b465-3424c8d437a6")>]
```

**find_elements_by_xpath** выдает такой же результат.

Подскажите, пожплуйста, почему или что делаю не так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Можно ссылку на ресурс?